# Saving an X509 certificate from an Azure Blob and using it in an Azure website

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate2

I have an Azure Website and an Azure Blob that I'm using to store a *.cer* X509 certificate file.

The goal is to get the *.cer* file from the blob and use it to perform an operation (the code for that is in the `Controller` for my Azure website and it works).

When I run the code locally (without publishing my site) it works, because I save it in `D:\`

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);

// Create the blob client. 
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myContainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "testcert.cer".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("testcert.cer");

// Save blob contents to a file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("D:/testcert.cer"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}


 **string certLocation = "D:/testcert.cer";
 X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2();

 myCert.Import(certLocation);**
```

I am unable to figure out how/where I can save it. If I try and use the Import method but enter a url (that of the Azure blob where the certificate is stored) I get an error because Import can't handle urls.

Any idea what I can use as temp storage on the Azure website or in the blob and create an `X509Certificate` from it?

**Edit:** I'm trying to add more detail about the problem I'm trying to solve.

1. Get a cert file from an Azure blob and write it to an Azure website.
2. Use the .Import(`string pathToCert`) on an `X509Certificate` object to create the cert which will be used to make a call in a method I've written in my controller.

I've been able to work around 1 by manually adding the `.cer` file to the wwwroot folder of my site via FTP. But now when I use `Server.MapPath("~/testcert.cer");` to get the path for my certificate I get this: `D:\home\site\wwwroot\testcert.cer`

Obviously when the Import method uses the string above as a path once it's deployed to my azure website, it's not a valid path and so my cert creation fails.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Watch this space: Better support for handing certificates in Azure Websites coming soon :)

Answer (score 6):

Saving the certificate locally is generally a no-no for Azure, you've got BlobStorage for that.

Use the Import(byte[]) overload to keep and load the certificate in memory.  Here's a quick hand coded attempt...

```
  // Used to store the certificate data
  byte[] certData;
  // Save blob contents to a memorystream.
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(stream);
        certData = stream.ToArray();
  }

  X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2();
  // Import from the byte array
  myCert.Import(certData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. And the answer covers all and any web hosters, not just Azure.

First of all, I would highly recommend that you **never** statically put a path to a folder in your Web Projects! Then what you can do is:

1. User the `Server.MapPath("~/certs")` method to obtain the physical path of a `certs` folder within your web site root folder.
2. Make Sure that no one can access this folder from the outside world:

[image: Location Deny content]

By adding this additional `location` section in your web.config you are blocking any external access to this folder. Please note that `location`element has to be direct descendant of the root `configuration` element in your web.config file.

**UPDATE** with non-azure relevant part on how to write file to local file system of a ASP.NET web project:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/certs"); 
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path + "\testcert.cer")) 
{
  // here use the fileStream to write
}
```

And a complete sample code on how to use Blob Stroage client to write content of a blob to a local file:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/certs");  
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path + "\testcert.cer"))  
{   
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream ); 
}
```

But, @SeanCocteau has a good point and much simpler approach - just use `MemoryStream` instead!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know I can use Server.MapPath("~/certs") to get the cert from the root folder. How do I save the cert there in the first place? What should I change the OpenWrite("path") to?

// Save blob contents to a file.
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("D:/testcert.cer"))
        {
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
        }

Comment: var path = Server.MapPath("~/certs");
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path + "\testcert.cer"))

Answer (score 0):

You can now upload your certificates via the Portal, add an app setting to your site, and have the certificate show up in your site's Certificate Store.

See this blog post for more details:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/